# Check if a hash of two key value pairs consists of only false values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know, what would be the easiest way to determinate if a hash with 2 key/value pairs only consists of false values

```
hash = {key1: false, key2: false}
```

how can I check for this in a condition. I know about `all?` but I'm curious if there would be something even simpler because of the fact, its only 2 values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if there's two or 200 `all?` is a very straightforward way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_hash.values.uniq == [false]
```

or

```
my_hash.invert.keys == [false]
```

Comment: This is the best one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland why is the false in brackets? Comparing two arrays?

Comment: I find more readable 
my_hash.values.all? { |value| value == false }

Comment: Supersize, `uniq` returns an array of unique values. `[false]` is an array containing the single object `false`.

Answer (score 4):

this could also be an option

```
hash = old_hash.dup
hash.delete_if {|x,v| v == false} == {}
```

Bench-marking I did

```
hash = {key1: false, key2: false, key3: false, key4: false}
n = 100000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    n.times do
      hash.values.uniq == [false] 
    end
  end
end

 #  user     system      total        real
 #  0.110000   0.000000   0.110000 (  0.103477)



hash = {key1: false, key2: false, key3: false, key4: false}
n = 100000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report do
    n.times do
      hash.delete_if {|x,v| v == false} == {}
    end
  end
end

   # user     system      total        real
   # 0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.026449)
```

However, I believe the code should be more readable as possible so I would recommend the answer of @Cary Swoveland

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, the hash values can not be `nil` (which is falsey):

```
hash.values.none?
```

or, for precise check on `false`, not `falsey`:

```
hash.values.all? { |e| e == false } # this works with `nil`s properly
```

or:

```
!hash.values.reduce(&:|)
```

or (just out of curiosity):

```
hash.values.uniq.tap do |a| 
  raise if a.pop == false && a.empty?
end.first rescue true
```

or:

```
hash.values == [false] * hash.size
```

Comment: It is not good to use two negations `none?` and `!=`. You should go with `all?{|e| e == false}`.

Comment: @sawa of course, you are right, it’s a matter of copy-paste. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
hash.values.uniq.length == 1 && hash.values.uniq.include?(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way for two keys:

```
!(hash[:key1] || hash[:key2])
#=> true
```

One disadvantage: will return `true` for `nil` values too.